# What is the purpose of the sign "!" after after the "$" in angular observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular-tour-of-heroes

I saw in the Angular tour of heroes tutorial, they declare `hero$!: Observable<Hero>;`

Why is there `!` sign after the `$` ?

They are also initializing the hero observable in the `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.hero$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        this.service.getHero(params.get('id')!))
    );
  }
```

And there, we also see the `!` sign on `params.get('id')!`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions

Comment: @Jayce444, thank you, this answers my question, I was not sure if it was a Angular or Typescript feature